# OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture(0) doesn't work

Tags: opencv, raspicam

The question is a bit similar to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-cant-opencv-open-my-videocapture-device).

The main difference is that I'm using a different camera (the Raspberry Pi camera board). I've spend a few days exploring Python and OpenCV. I'm writing a script on my Windows laptop that I want to run on my Raspberry Pi.

My Raspberry Pi has OpenCV 2.3.1 installed. I could make images using [PiCamera](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/picamera), or I could write:

```
import os, sys
os.system('raspistill -o /var/www/images/image.jpg')
```

However, I want to use [cv2.VideoCapture(int device)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture%20read#videocapture-videocapture). The documentation says:

> **Parameters:**
>
> - **filename** – name of the opened video file
> - **device** – id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera    index). If there is a single camera connected, just pass 0.

`cv2.CreateCapture(0)` works perfectly fine on my laptop. On the Raspberry Pi however, it's unable to open the camera. I'm not experienced with Raspbian, so I'm not sure if `0` is the correct device ID.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’ve had a similar issue an found that adding a 500 ms wait to allow the window to initialize works.

Answer (score 3):

Until recently this wasn't possible - it requires a V4L2 driver for the camera which was previously absent. This is now available, just follow the instructions [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364) to set up the driver and cv2 videocapture should work fine.